# is it possible to force a full-page figure to go inside the list of references? (BibTeX)

Tags: floats, bibtex

The usual question is "How do I get my figure to *not* get placed inside the reference list?" I am asking the opposite.

I *want* a certain figure to go on the first page after the references begin.  When the page with the figure has enough space for at least one reference to appear then this is easy to do.  Unfortunately, my figure takes up the whole page.  Is there some trick I could apply?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea here is to hook into the `\bibliography` command, and use that to hook into the next page.  That way, TeX can figure out when to include the picture, and we don't have to worry about adjusting the bibliography.  With an up to date TeXLive (2021 or later), we can use the hook system (see lthooks-doc.pdf and ltshipout-doc.pdf). Otherwise, we need to bring in a few packages.

```tex
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{one,
  author = {Smith, A.},
  title = {A Title},
  journal = {A Journal},
  year = {2021}
}
@article{two,
  author = {Smith, A.},
  title = {A Title},
  journal = {A Journal},
  year = {2022}
}
@article{three,
  author = {Smith, A.},
  title = {A Title},
  journal = {A Journal},
  year = {2023}
}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx}
% with TeXLive 2021+
\AddToHookNext{cmd/bibliography/before}{%
 \AddToHookNext{shipout/before}{%
  \includegraphics[height=\textheight,width=\textwidth]{example-image}%
  \clearpage%
 }%
}
% with any TeXLive
%\usepackage{etoolbox}
%\usepackage{atbegshi}
%\pretocmd{\bibliography}{%
% \AtBeginShipoutNext{%
%  \includegraphics[height=\textheight,width=\textwidth]{example-image}%
%  \clearpage%
% }%
%}{}{}

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}

\begin{document}
For more on this, see\\\cite{one},\\\cite{two}, and\\\cite{three}.

\lipsum[1-4]

\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```